# Trouble with reading and appending to ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream

Tags: java, file, serialization

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Main
{
    static ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    static ObjectInputStream inputStream;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("Test.ser");
        outputStream = openWriteFile(file);
        write(new Integer(5));
        write(new Integer(3));
        write(new Integer(1));

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream = openReadFile(fileInputStream);
        readFile();
    }

    public static ObjectOutputStream openWriteFile(File file)
    {
        try
        {
            if (file.exists())
                return new AppendableObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));

            return new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        }

        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void write(Integer i)
    {
        try
        {
            outputStream.write(i); 
        }

        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            System.err.println("error");
        }
    }

    public static ObjectInputStream openReadFile(FileInputStream fileInputStream)
    {
        try
        {
            if(fileInputStream.getChannel().position() != 0)
                return new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            return new AppendableObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
        }

        catch (IOException ioException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void readFile()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("here");
                Integer integer = (Integer) inputStream.readObject();
                System.out.println("after");
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
        }

        catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException)
        {
            classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.err.println("ioexecption");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private static class AppendableObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream
    {

        public AppendableObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException
        {
            super(out);
        }

        @Override
        protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException
        {
            // do not write a header
        }
    }

    private static class AppendableObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream
    {

        public AppendableObjectInputStream(InputStream in) throws IOException
        {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        protected void readStreamHeader() throws IOException
        {
            // do not read a header
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
here
ioexecption
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: AC
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Main.readFile(Main.java:79)
    at Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

I'm having some trouble reading back from the .ser file I wrote to. I've ran the program a couple of times and used `getClass()` and found that both streams are the `Appendable` version of the streams. The message "here" is printed to the console but not "after". "Test.ser" appears in the same directory as the `classpath` and contains the content "¬í".

Comment: Modify your code so that you can see the stacktrace and the details of the exception that is being thrown on the line after println("here"), then add that (the stacktrace) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with inputs and outputs, you should look for symmetry: if you write a byte on one side, you read a byte on the other side. If you write an object on one side, you read an oject on the other side.

Your code writes 3 bytes, and attempts to read objects. That can't work.

I also don't understand what you're trying to achieve with your appendable streams.

Comment: I have to write objects and append new ones to an existing file and read them back, so I was trying to test it out in a smaller program. I thought it would work the same way if I cast `int`s to `Integer`?

Comment: If you use readObject() to read something, it must have been written using writeObject(). Read the javadoc for write(): it doesn't do the same thing as writeObject().

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to readObject() and made it read and write an object from a class I made called AccountRecord, but I'm still getting the same error